# Function pointer on generic class delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I need to get a FunctionPointerForDelegate to pass a native P/Invoke, but the function resides in a generic class of type myClass

When I try to create the Pointer I get an error of

```
System.ArgumentException: 'The specified Type must not be a generic type. (Parameter 'delegate')'
```

Is there any workaround to this?

```
var c = new MyClass<int>();
c.DoWork();

public class MyClass<T> {

    private protected delegate int MyCompareCallback(int idxA, int idxB);

    private int SortCompareFunction(int idxA, int idxB) {
        return -1; // simplified implementation
    }

    public void DoWork() {
        MyCompareCallback SortCallback = new(SortCompareFunction);
        IntPtr callbackPtr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(SortCallback);
        Console.WriteLine("Success"); // Fails on previous line with System.ArgumentException: 'The specified Type must not be a generic type. (Parameter 'delegate')'
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code so we can see what doesn't work?

Comment: Please read [ask] and ***fix your question***. Right now it's unclear what you're doing and your question is likely to get closed.

Comment: Apologize, I guess I forgot a chunk of the code of course, my mistake.

Comment: Could you please read [ask] and also [mcve] and then post enough code for us to copy-and-paste (plus any instructions on references or NuGet required) and see what doesn't work for you? I've been coding C# for nearly 25 years and I can't get the small snippet you've provided to get close to compiling.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes sir...

Comment: That is a limitation of the runtime. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d8141743fecaeff4711112ca08a3226ac5d68011/src/coreclr/vm/comdelegate.cpp#L1233 So write a non-generic class with a function to act as a proxy....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider that your delegate type `MyCompareCallback` is actually `MyClass<T>.MyCompareCallback`. It is a generic type.

When you read the documentation for [Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getfunctionpointerfordelegate?view=net-8.0#system-runtime-interopservices-marshal-getfunctionpointerfordelegate-1(-0)) it specifically says the `System.ArgumentException` will be thrown if the delegate is a generic type.

You really have two choices.

(1) remove the generic type parameter from `MyClass`

```
public class MyClass
{
    private protected delegate int MyCompareCallback(int idxA, int idxB);
    private int SortCompareFunction(int idxA, int idxB) => -1;
    public void DoWork()
    {
        MyCompareCallback SortCallback = new MyCompareCallback(SortCompareFunction);
        IntPtr callbackPtr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(SortCallback);
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
    }
}
```

(2) move the delegate outside of `MyClass<T>`

```
internal delegate int MyCompareCallback(int idxA, int idxB);
public class MyClass<T>
{
    private int SortCompareFunction(int idxA, int idxB) => -1;
    public void DoWork()
    {
        MyCompareCallback SortCallback = new MyCompareCallback(SortCompareFunction);
        IntPtr callbackPtr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(SortCallback);
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
    }
}
```